# AngularJS - after separate templates javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-routing, angular-seed

I bought a template which should not have problem with AngularJS according authors. When I have one big index then everything works fine. But the problem is when I try to separate it into the smaller template. I have downloaded new AngularJS seed and just did this:

```
.. header
.. body

  <div ng-view></div>


  <!-- Vendor Scripts Bundle -->
  <script src="vendor.min.js"></script>
  <!-- App Scripts Bundle -->
  <script src="scripts.min.js"></script>

.. angularJS files
```

Route to the smaller template works fine, the content is visible, but just these two javascript libraries doesn't work. When I look at code in chrome inspect I see that libraries exist. Is necessary to register them somewhere in AngularJS or must be problem in these libraries?

Comment: any errors on console? f12

Comment: can you add a plunker link with your code?

Comment: here is: http://plnkr.co/edit/jzHaZM7Elr2n2rAZwJxC

Answer (score 0):

Whatever AngularJS components you define outside AngularJS will remain outside AngularJS - unless they are integrated at ".config()" state of the app.

The global objects should be usable though (e.g. $ for jQuery); although cleanly would be defined as constants.

The question is pretty generic, I think you need to provide more insight into that to get some proper help, as the comments above stated.

Answer (score 0):

I saw 2 errors at console on plunker.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined app.js:10
Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute
```

Looking at your code I see a few errors. First of all you're using 1.0.x version of AngularJS. In those versions ngRoute is not a separate module so you shouldn't include that. Also you defined view1 modules as `view1` but tried to include as `myApp.view1`. When you fix those issues your code should work.